# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, Undirected Graph

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me and tell me why does this error happen?

I've searched other threads and still can't find the problem.
It works for the first line, so there are two arguments, but it fails on the inverse.
Please help.

```
const airports='PHX BKK OKC JFK LAX MEX EZE HEL LOS LAP LIM'.split(' ');

const routes = [
['PHX', 'LAX'],
['PHX', 'JFK'], 
['JFK', 'OKH'],
['JFK', 'HEL'],
['JFK', 'LOS'],
['MEX', 'LAX'],
['MEX', 'BKK'],
['MEX', 'LIM'],
['MEX', 'EZE'],
['LIM', 'BKK'],
];

const adjacencyList= new Map();

function addNode(airport) {

 adjacencyList.set(airport, []);

}


function addEdge(origin, destination) {


    adjacencyList.get(origin).push(destination);


    adjacencyList.get(destination).push(origin);

}

airports.forEach(addNode);


routes.forEach(route => addEdge(...route));


console.log(adjacencyList)
```

Comment: That is because you have a typo in your `routes` list - line 3: There is no airport with name 'OKH'.

Comment: Heaven's sake,I looked everywhere but on the damn names.Thank  you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `OKH` is not part of the string that contains all `airports`, so it's missing from the `adjacencyList` and returns `undefined` when you try to do `adjacencyList.get(destination).push(origin)`, hence the error.

```js
const airports = "PHX BKK OKC JFK LAX MEX EZE HEL LOS LAP LIM".split(" ");

const routes = [
  ["PHX", "LAX"],
  ["PHX", "JFK"],
  ["JFK", "OKH"],
  ["JFK", "HEL"],
  ["JFK", "LOS"],
  ["MEX", "LAX"],
  ["MEX", "BKK"],
  ["MEX", "LIM"],
  ["MEX", "EZE"],
  ["LIM", "BKK"]
];

const adjacencyList = new Map();

function addNode(airport) {
  adjacencyList.set(airport, []);
}

function addEdge(origin, destination) {
  adjacencyList.get(origin).push(destination);
  const dest = adjacencyList.get(destination);

  if (!dest) {
    addNode(destination)
  }
  adjacencyList.get(destination).push(origin);
}

airports.forEach(addNode);

routes.forEach(route => addEdge(...route));

console.log("result");
adjacencyList.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(key, value);
});
```